# I am trying to write a DAX query for ranking using RANKX which i can later use for TOP N analysis

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to write the DAX to get ranking of stores based on sales. The codeprovided calculates the rank of stores based on their total weekly sales in the 'sales data-set'. But i an geting the same rank (rank 1) for all rows below is the code:-

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eE3x.png)

Rank of Stores =
RANKX(
ALL('sales data-set'),  -- Replace 'Stores' with the appropriate table name
CALCULATE(SUM('sales data-set'[Weekly_Sales])),
,
DESC
)

I am trying to get the ranking which i can use to do TOP N analysis where N is coming from parameter.